# programmatically changing height of view ignores constraints

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem on constraints on view when programmatically changing its frame.

So I have the following layout. What I intended to do is when the yellow view is clicked, the date picker view(Open Hour Picker) expands in between the yellow bar(first bar) and the bars below. As the Open Hour Picker expands, the bars below move down. The way I expands the Open Hour Picker is that Open Hour Picker starts with height 0, and when yellow bar clicked, the Open Hour Picker expands its height using UIView.animate().

The second image shows the constraints on the second darkgray bar.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically when constraints are being ignored the first thing you want to do is make sure you're setting:

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```